# In「～てこ」, what does the こ do?

Tags: て-form

There are some lyrics in the song VOICE by Perfume that go:

> 点と点を繋げてこ
>   everythingを合わせてこ

I've no idea how こ functions here as I don't think I've encountered it before like this.
The group are from [広島]{ひろしま} if that helps, though I couldn't find anything about it on the wiki for 広島弁. It's probably something really simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Hiroshima dialect.

～～てこ　＝　～～ていこう (volitional form of ～～ていく)

てこ is just a colloquial pronunciation.

～～てこ = "Let's go ~~ing!" or simply "Let's ~~!"

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I didn't think it would be anything to do with Hiroshima dialect but I thought I should point that out just in case. Thanks :)